HtmlAgilityPack - results are mixed up
So, I want to create an application that periodically get's HTML from a product selling pages that the user provides.
The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the values so that they don't get mixed up.
You can see on the image that title of the ad doesn't match the URL (title says iPhone 13, URL says iPhone 5s):

var url = url_textbox.Text;
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);

var allTitles = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='" + adTitleClassName + "']"); // exam: adTitleClassName = css-1wxaaza
var allPrices = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='" + adPriceClassName + "']");
var allLinks = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='" + adLinkClassName + "']");
var allDamaged = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='" + adDamagedClassName + "']");
var allLocations = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='" + adLocationClassName + "']");
var allImages = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='css-gl6djm']");

for (int i = 0; i < allTitles.Count; i++)
{
    var title = allTitles[i].InnerText;
    var price = allPrices[i].InnerText;
    var link = allLinks[i].Attributes["href"].Value;
    var damaged = allDamaged[i].InnerText;
    var timeAdded = allLocations[i].InnerText;
    var imageUrl = allImages[i].SelectNodes("//img/@src")[i].Attributes["src"].Value;
    var negotiate = false;

    var damagedParsed = false;
    if (damaged == "Uszkodzone") damagedParsed = true;

    Ad ad = new Ad();
    ad.Title = title;
    ad.Price = double.Parse(price.Replace("do negocjacji", "").Replace(" zł", "").Replace(" ", ""));
    ad.URL = "https://www.olx.pl" + link;
    ad.Damaged = damagedParsed;
    ad.TimeAdded = timeAdded;
    ad.ImageURL = imageUrl;
    ad.Negotiate = price.Contains("do negocjacji");

    if (only_iphone_checkBox.Checked)
    {
        if (ad.Title.ToLower().Contains("iphone") ||
            ad.Title.ToLower().Contains("apple")) ads.Add(ad);
    } else
    {
        ads.Add(ad);
    }
}

foreach (Ad ad in ads)
{
    AdItem adItem = new AdItem(ad);
    ads_list.Controls.Add(adItem);
}

So, I thought it was because it tries to get all the information separately and packs it into different lists, making the information get mixed up.
So I tried getting the information together, separately for each card with an item for sale that displays on the page, with this code:
var url = url_textbox.Text;
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);

var mainCard = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='AdCardId']");
for (int i = 0; i < mainCard.Count; i++)
{
    var title = mainCard[i].SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='" + adTitleClassName + "']").InnerText;
    Print(title); // It prints always the same title
}

result of the code above:

So, it really doesn't make sense to me - why the 'SelectNodes' method doesn't really 'select' as the name of the method says?
I assume that
var title = mainCard[i].SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='" + adTitleClassName + "']").InnerText;

is trying to find the adTitleClassName in the whole HTML page instead of the node I selected, that's why I get the same title for each product.
How I could get ONLY the node with the card that represents the AD, instead of whole HTML?

Single page apps exchange data with the server behind the scenes with JS without changing the URL. I.e., the same URL can dynamically change the content. Search for "scraping single page apps".

Fixed!
I didn't know that several expressions can be used in the “SelectSingleNode” method.
var url = url_textbox.Text;
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);

var mainCards = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='css-1sw7q4x']");
for (int i = 0; i < mainCards.Count; i++)
{
    
    if (mainCards[i].Attributes["id"] != null)
    {
        var id = mainCards[i].Attributes["id"].Value; // Get ID of the card

        var card = mainCards[i];

        // Select node where id == var id and class == var adTitleClassName
        Print(card.SelectSingleNode($"//div[@id='{id}']//*[@class='{adTitleClassName}']").InnerText, DEBUG_TYPE.DO_NOT_PRINT);
    }
    else
    {
        // ID == NULL
    }
}


You can accept your own answer (click the checkmark on the left) to close the question.
